# Can I change the MP3 encoder in Cubase Elements 7?

Tags: mp3, cubase, encoding

When trying to export MP3 format directly from Cubase I get an error regarding licensing: "No more encodings"

I have Audacity, which uses the LAME encoder to make MP3 files. Currently the only way I can make an mp3 is to export a WAV file, load it into Audacity and then export an MP3 from there. Which, although tedious isn't the end of the world for quick edits and rough cuts.

But is there a way to just use the LAME mp3 encoder directly from the Cubase or use some other encoder? I don't mind paying a little bit for a decent mp3 encoder, but I do a lot of quick jams and ad-hoc recordings and don't want to be paying on a per-encoding model where I get charged for each mp3 I make.

Comment: Talk to Steinberg - the licence should include Fraunhofer - it's been years since the licensing was separate. [I'm sure I've got one dongle with a separate Fraunhofer license on it... now I'm going to have to go find it... ;)

Comment: The last time I tried to contact Steinberg support (because my eLicencer stopped working when windows did an update) it took them about four *months* to respond to my query.... so I'll ask them, but I'll probably have written my own Mp3 encoder before they reply...

Comment: Can you confirm that the latest version (Cubase Elements 9) has MP3 encoding included - I see I could upgrade for £24 which might be worth it if it solves the problem ;)

Comment: I couldn't say, sorry. I've never had Elements, I have the full 'studio' version [or whatever its name is this year, it's changed somewhat over the past 30 years ;) though I'm still on v8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't purchased the MP3 encoder upgrade. Cubase Elements does not come with an MP3 encoder by itself, just a trial. Once you have used the trial limit of conversions, you will get an error saying "No more encodings."

Cubase Elements series does not come with an encoder, only the Full version (not sure about Artist). You can either purchase the encoder (and you'll get to use it permanently, not on a 'per-encoding' basis), or export as wav and use Audacity to export to MP3 (as you are doing).

As far as linking the LAME encoder, I haven't been able to find a way, and feel like you won't be able to. Maybe someone else will know better though.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware it didn't come as part of the package in Elements.